# A (imaginary) point or An (imaginary) point

Tags: spoken-english, spelling

A or An is usually decided by whether you pronounce the beginning of the following word as a consonant or not. Does a word in parentheses count as ' following'?

**A (imaginary) point** or **An (imaginary) point**

Comment: In terms of *grammar*, what's inside parentheses should have no impact whatsoever in terms of what's outside the parentheses. So, strictly speaking, it should be *a (imaginary) point*, and the *an* is ungrammatical. However, style frequently overrides grammar in situations like this. A lot of people would use *an (imaginary) point* just because it *sounds* better. But, as the answer indicates, you can rephrase it so you're not stuck with a choice between grammar and style.

Comment: @JasonBassford that's a good point, but I would ask what you would say when *speaking* the sentence. I have wondered about the use of "an" when writing, since it is relevant to speech.

Comment: @WeatherVane If I were speaking it, nothing would be parenthetical in the first place:  *an imaginary point*. Otherwise, I would deliberately pause and use *a*: *a—imaginary—point*. I would also pronounce the letter as *ay*, not *uh*.

Answer (score 3):

That might be a question of style. I would use "an" since I will read through the parenthesized text, and the meaning is perfectly clear.

> An (imaginary) point . . .

If necessary you could avoid it with

> A point (possibly imaginary) . . .